# Get SPL Token Metadata

Tags: blockchain, solana, metaplex

I recently come across Solana Blockchain, I'm wondering is it possible to fetch the token metadata directly without using any third-party services? Thanks for your help!

I have tried Metaplex but it did not work, if this package usable, is there a proper way to archive it?